# After upgrading to version 4.3.1 wordpress can no longer publish

Tags: wordpress

Yesterday updated the new version of wordpress to some sites that I maintain. But in all the following problem: When creating a new post and click the publish button, nothing is published, it is always as a draft, the process of publishing does not end.

Comment: Did Wordpress update the database during the upgrade process?

Comment: I think not, did not see any proceedings on the database.

Comment: Have you tried, downloading a fresh copy of 4.3.1 and uploading that via FTP and overwrite your existing files?

Comment: Yes man, but didn't work.

Comment: Restore from your backup :) 4.3.1 was a pretty significant patch. Have you tried disabling plugins/changing theme to rule conflicts out?

Comment: All the sites I've updated to 4.3.1 are able to publish just fine, so I don't think it's an issue with the files. Could very possibly be caused by a plugin. Have you looked at your access and error PHP logs?

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, I can't comment yet cause I don't have enough points.)

I am seeing the same issue.

"Quick Edit" in the Posts lists works, but Editing the post does not.
Some odd behaviours:

- Update & Publish fail by a) not saving any of the Post's information or settings to the database and b) pushing the user out to the All Posts List
- Version Control notification that what is currently in the text box is not the same as what is cached. Regardless if I Undo or not, Update & Publish both fail.
- Editing old posts and creating new posts, same problem.
- Bewilderingly, *sometimes* it goes through. But so randomly I have yet to figure out why.

My guess is there is some conflict between the version checking, auto-save and perhaps content checker (html?).

Sorry I can't be of more help. Hope someone figures this out... Posting posts is the *one* thing I expect Wordpress to do. It has *one* job, so to speak. ;)

Comment: you should answer to other questions to gain reputation. so you can comment

Comment: thanks for the helpful comment @urfusion. I'll try to engage more in S.O., but in the meantime this issue was pressing to me and the OP.